# Is it really safe when using android 6.0 run time permission?

Tags: android, android-manifest, expo

One of our developers made android application with all permission in manifest.xml (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, USE_FINGERPRINT ect.).

I guided him to remove unnecessary permission then he told me, "It is safe, because he used android 6.0 run-time permission (pop up the permission)".

But I think it is not safe because it can be abused.

Do I think wrong?

Comment: You are right. It can be abused and end users may not install the application. Please note that they will see all permissions you declared in Manifest.xml, if the see something which is not make-sense (i.e send SMS, but your project is not related to), they will think your application is a malware.

Comment: Thank you Cao. But it's really hard to persuade him. Because this app can be used in our company only.

Comment: One more thing is it will increase the size of the Apk file. Yeah, we all have to face some stubborn developers

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of permissions, normal and dangerous. All declared normal permissions are in effect if declared in the manifest.If the app min sdk is Android 6.0 and above, until the user grants the permissions at runtime, the dangerous permissions are not in effect. It doesn't matter if they are declared in the manifest.It may be dangerous if the user grants the app dangerous permissions and you allow other apps to access some resources using your apps permissions like PendingIntent.

Comment: As your say, if all dangerous permissions are also in the manifest.xml and it is allowed but without pendingintent it is safe, right?

Comment: Well yes, because no other app can access your files on example, only your app can use those permissions. As far as I figured it out your concern is if other apps can abuse the permissions from your app, they can't. And if the user's of your app don't want to give the permission  when requested, they can deny it because from Android 6 all dangerous permissions are requested at run time right when they are needed. On example if you declared permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL, it won't be avtive until the user grants your app access at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Cao Minh Vu 
**It is better to request permissions which your app really requires.If you request a permission that is not required by your app users may think your app is malware.**

*For Example:*

> If you are requesting permissions for camera which is not required for your App even though giving permission or denying it is up to the user but it may cause user to be skeptical.And Probably user may uninstall your Application.